# Creating tasks simultaneously, freeze.

Tags: development, workflow, visual-studio

I am working with two workflows,  both of them have been done in C# by using Visual Studio within SharePoint 2007 , the first one is activated when a document has been updated and copies the file into another library multiple times.
On the second library the second workflow starts when the item is created, (one per each item), this workflow is an approval workflow.
The problem starts on the second workflow, when the item is created the approval task starts however when is updated the tasks do not pick the updates up. If I try to edit the task again, it returns an error: "This task is currently locked by a running workflow and cannot be edited"
Do you know anything about this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to share that I found a solution in here:
http://addictedtosharepoint.com/category/sharepoint2010/

my problem was that I gave one guid as taskid as many web sites suggests, I have updated the code to create a new guid for task and worked really well.